# asp.net c# - sudden infinite redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

We have migrated one of our projects from ms.net 2.0 to 3.5.

The website is hosted on Windows 2008 R2 Server and the clients are Windows 7 32 bit, Chrome or IE10

All users after working for some time, get a "infinite redirect loop" message in Chrome. IE doesn't show up any message, only a blank window. This gets cleared if both iis is reset and the browser cache is cleared.

Since the issue gets resolved if the above is done, I think it is not a problem with the code.

Is this correct? Or is it something to do with the code only.

Comment: It's really hard to tell if its code error if we can't see even a sample of code. Is this for a specific page or does this happen on random pages?

Comment: This can happen if there is an error page that is shown for uncaught exceptions, and that error page is in a location where authentication is required, and you have a login page that in some cases throws an exception. This can cause a cycle of redirects where the login page throw an exception, Asp.Net tries to show the error page which requires authentication which causes a redirect to the login pages etc. This has actually happened to me. So start by checking if you login page may trow Exceptions...